# Angular Grid (ag-grid) show/hide not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-grid

I am using Angular Grid (ag-grid) to display data.  In my gridOptions, I use `cellClicked` to call a function when one of the columns is clicked. That function, `SeeDetails` simply sets a variable on the scope to true or false to hide/show the div containing the `ag-grid`. It does not work for some reason.

To test, I created a button outside the `ag-grid` which calls the same `SeeDetails` function. When doing it this way, the div hides the grid just fine (in my html, I have `ng-show="vm.ShowDetails == 'false'"` to show hide the grid).

I am thinking it has something to do with scope, just not sure what. Any ideas?

HTML:

```
<div ng-show="vm.ShowDetails == 'false'">
    <div style="height: 800px" ag-grid="vm.gridOptions" class="ag-fresh"></div>
</div>
```

VIEWMODEL:

```
var vm = this;
vm.ShowDetails = 'false';

vm.gridOptions = {
    rowData: null,
    enableColResize: true,
    enableSorting: true,
    enableFilter:  true,
    columnDefs: [
        {
            field: 'LogID',
            headerName: 'Log ID a',
            width: 100
        }, {
            headerName: 'Log ID',
            name: 'Log ID',
            cellClicked: function (params) {
                vm.SeeDetails(params.data.LogID);
            },
            cellRenderer: function (params) {
                return '<a>' + params.data.LogID + '</a>';
            }
        }, {
            headerName: 'Date Of Error',
            name: 'Col Name',
            cellRenderer: function (params) {
                return moment(params.data.TimeOfError).format('DD/MMM/YYYY')
                //return params.data.TimeOfError;
            }
        }
    ]
};

vm.SeeDetails = function SeeDetails(LogID) {
    if (vm.ShowDetails == 'false') {
        vm.ShowDetails = 'true';
    } else {
        vm.ShowDetails = 'false';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The digest cycle is not called by ag-grid on this particular callback.

To fix, just make sure the digest cycle is kicked off.

Do this by:

```
vm.SeeDetails = function SeeDetails(LogID) {
    if (vm.ShowDetails == 'false') {
        vm.ShowDetails = 'true';
    } else {
        vm.ShowDetails = 'false';
    }
    setTimeout( function() { $scope.$apply(); }, 0 );
}
```

The timeout is done as a guard, to make sure the digest cycle is not already running. Calling the native timeout instead of using the angular timeout service is required, as the angular one will guarantee a digest is running (which you don't want).

Answer (score 0):

```
$timeout(function() {
     $scope.gridOptions.api.checkGridSize()
});
```

Worked for me.